# Marit ayin vs. Dan Lechaf zechut

Tags: halacha-theory, marit-ayin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“bad impression” vs “Judge your friend favorably”](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14694/bad-impression-vs-judge-your-friend-favorably)

Why does the prohibition of maris ayin apply when there is also a mitzvah of hevei dan es kol ha-adam l'khaf z'khus?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14694/1172)?