# The source to be Dan L'Caf Zechut

Tags: sources-mekorot, bein-adam-lachavero

From where do we know that one must be "dan" someone "l'caf zechut"? (that we must judge someone favorably even though from a certain act it might seem they are doing something?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14694/3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Gemora (Shavuos 30a) derives from the verse (Vayikra 19:15) "בצדק תשפוט עמיתך" ("You shall judge your fellow with righteousness") that one should judge others favorably.

Answer (score 8):

In Pirkei Avos [1:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2165/jewish/Chapter-One.htm):

> יהושע בן פרחיה אומר, עשה לך רב, וקנה לך חבר יג, והוי דן את כל האדם **לכף זכות**.‏
>
> Joshua the son of Perachia would say: Assume for yourself a master, acquire for yourself a friend, and judge every man to the side of merit.

Comment: Sounds more like good advice than an obligation.